# Pronunciation of 対応済

Tags: readings, phonology, suffixes, rendaku

Is the pronunciation of `対応済` `たいおうすみ` or `たいおうずみ` ?

Context: Software

Example:

```
ユーザが押したときに問題が起こらないように対応済
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is たいおうずみ.  More generally, the [suffix 済 or 済み](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BF&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=110511200000) is read as ずみ.  This is an example of [rendaku](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendaku).

Comment: Thanks! It was a basic question, but strangely I could not find the answer on Google nor ALC. Sometimes rendaku is not applied, so I am never really sure for new composite words.

Comment: @Nicolas: You may want to wait for a while before accepting my answer, because someone may be able to provide a _verifiable_ answer.  I do not have any dictionary which shows the pronunciation of 対応済, but I suspect that NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 may contain the pronunciation of it.

Comment: I realized that suffix 済 does not change its pronunciation depending on the word it is attached to, and therefore it was much easier to answer the question with a verifiable source.